# Is it possible to find eigenvalues (and vectors) using Dask, and if so, how?

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I am only just starting to look into Dask. I think it might be practical for a script which today uses numpy functions, but which I guess could be "upgraded" for solving even bigger problems by using Dask. So pretty much the "center" of the script is to find eigenvalues and -vectors. This is done via `np.linalg.eigh` today.

It seems that right now, Dask does not have a `da.linalg.eigh` function. Is there a way to achieve this through other (dask) means, or do I have to stick with the previous numpy approach?

Comment: I don't think anyone has implemented `eig` or `eigh` for dask.array yet.  You could [open an issue](http://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new).  I recommend mentioning @sinhrks in the issue to see if he's interested.

Comment: Opened issue an issue on this point. ( https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2618 )